# Custom (irregular) polygons as feature Styles in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to create a custom Polygon style for my layer style.

I receive some information about position, orientation and age for a number of objects and I want to represent those as zoom independent (like using Icons or RegularShapes) isosceles triangles, pointing at an angle and color-coded according to age.

I have a good idea of the color-coding and rotation part, but I'm stumped at creating an isosceles triangle using the style objects provided by OpenLayers.

This is what I have so far:

```
style = [new ol.style.Style({
    geometry: function(feature) {
        return new ol.geom.Polygon([[
            [0, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [1, 3]
        ]]);
    },
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#000'}) //black right now
})]
```

Comment: It looks like you solve your question. You could post the solution and finish this one.

Comment: Actually I had to change OL's source code to solve this one, so I can't say that counts as a solution...